# c#:WindowsForms - performance optimization when redrawing bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

In my program I have a picture box, containing a bitmap.(300x300 35kB .PNG file)

If 2 variables(x/z coord) are changed, I draw a new circle every second to the new position accordingly - a **timer** runs in the background, invoking this method.

```
void DrawEllipse()
{       
  // Retrieve the image.
  bChamber = new Bitmap(global::Project.Properties.Resources.driveChamber1);

  gChamber = Graphics.FromImage(bChamber);
  gChamber.FillEllipse(brushChamber, VirtualViewX(), VirtualViewY(), 10, 10);
  pictureBoxDriveView.Image = bChamber;        
}
```

Now I'm looking for ways to optimize the performance. Redrawing the pic every 0.2s e.g. slows the program so much, I cant do anything else.
But ultimately I need a more fluent movement of the circle, you can Imagine how it laggs with the 1000ms refresh rate.

Is there a better way to do this, then loading the whole bitmap every time?

Comment: I don't understand the correlation between changing variables and this method, it seems that the timer will always draw an elipse every second regardless of a change?

Comment: Of course there's a better way.  Trying to make winforms do graphics is a bit like trying to cook in the bathroom.  It's just the wrong tool.  Make a WPF control - throw a canvas on top of an image, bundle it into one, import with WPF Interop, draw on canvas.

Comment: J.. will look into WPF, thanks for the hint

Comment: Use a backgroundworker/thread for redrawing the bitmap so the GUI is still useable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Controls the way they were intended.

- do not redraw the Bitmap yourself.
- just load it 1x in the Picturebox.
- handle the Paint event of the picturebox to draw the ellipse
- invalidate the Picturebox whenever your coords change.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the circle ONE time in a control (PictureBox)

Put the control across the 300x300 picture box.

When, and only when, the variables change, update the location of the picturebox with the circle.

This way you prevent drawing too many times.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `DoubleBuffered` property of the form to `true`. This generally results in improved performance.

Also, you should put this

```
// Retrieve the image.
bChamber = new Bitmap(global::Project.Properties.Resources.driveChamber1);
```

In the class constructor.

Comment: I have to load the image every time the function gets called, or I draw a line instead of a single circle. The old circles are still there otherwise

Comment: I see. Well the `DoubleBuffered` trick still applies, and you can use @mtsiakiris's reply as it still creates a new bitmap, but only loads the image to memory once.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it does not load the image from disk every time, so it is less expensive.

```
private Image _origImage = new Bitmap(global::Project.Properties.Resources.driveChamber1);

void DrawEllipse()
{
    // Retrieve the image.
    Image bChamber = new Bitmap((Image)this._origImage.Clone());

    Graphics gChamber = Graphics.FromImage(bChamber);

    gChamber.FillEllipse(brushChamber, VirtualViewX(), VirtualViewY(), 10, 10);
    pictureBoxDriveView.Image = bChamber;
}
```

Comment: could enhance it to 200ms and still get a better performance this way :)